# Setting a Label Text using a Variable

Tags: c#

I'm doing an assignment for school where I need to read a user name (and generate a test score) and I want to use a label to display this information back to the user whenever they hit the "submit test" button from a Windows Form. I have tried a few different ways

`label3.Text = "{0} {1}", name, score;` failed

I have also tried:

`label3.Text = test.ToString();` has worked, but the GUI displays `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: (name) (score)`

Here is the snippet of code I am working with, if I need to post more please let me know.

```
private void btnSubmitTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rdm = new Random();
    int testScore = rdm.Next(0, 100);
    string score = testScore.ToString();

    string name = txtName.ToString();

    //Generate a new test that passes in 
    Test tests = new Test(name, score);

    label3.Text = tests.ToString();
}
```

I'm very new to C#, so if there is any extra useful information I am all ears.

Comment: Close, but what you want is actually the `Text` property of the `Textbox` object. Try this: `string name = txtName.Text` instead. Just like how you assign the `label3`'s Text property in your last line there. Is the `Test` class something you've created, or did the professor provide it? Because you're probably just going to get something you're not expecting there, as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Test(name, score)` returns, but you might try `label3.Text = tests.Name;` instead of `label3.Text = tests.ToString();`

Comment: What does your Test object look like? You probably need to access your properties and assign those to your label as a concatenation. The ToString() wont give you a string representation of your object. So label3.text = tests.PropertyName + tests.PropertyName2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get or set the text of a `Textbox`, then use its `Text` property.
And calling `ToString()` on a new object will not  get you the result you expected unless you overrode the `ToString()` method.

Try it like this

```
private void btnSubmitTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Random rdm = new Random();
                int testScore = rdm.Next(0, 100);
                string score = testScore.ToString();


                string name = txtName.Text;

                //Generate a new test that passes in 
                Test tests = new Test(name, score);

                label3.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", name, score);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it.

```
label3.Text = String.Format ("{0} {1}", name, score);
```

Comment: Or $@"{name} {score}" with C#6

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple

you have many ways to solve it

```
String.Format("bla {0} blabla {1}",var1,var2);
```

or

```
$"bla {var1} blabla {var2}";
```

> as you see this way is better than concatenate strings using `+ operator`

and one of the most efficient ways is to override `ToString()` Method in your `Class`

```
class Test
{
    private string _a;
    private int _b;

    public Test(string a, int b)
    {
       _a = a;
       _b = b;
    }

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return string.Format("{0}, {1}", _a, _b);
   }
}
```

this allow you to print out your object in in very resable way
just like this

```
Test test1=new Test("Hello All",1);
string TextObject = test1.ToString();
```

and this is the recommended way